# Twitter apps, by prompting for them to authorize my app am I then using their outh credentials? How does this effect rate limits?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I built a simple app that searches tweets with a keyword and then maps the ones with coordinates. I'd like to take it further and build a dashboard people could use to search tweets, reply to them, friend them, map them etc.

A few questions in getting started.

1. Right now it just uses my oauth to make the calls, if I were to have more users using the service and therefore more calls I would run into some issues, correct? When they login to the app and authorize it, do the calls come from their account?
2. Streaming api. I build the first with the search api, they enter a keyword and it searches. With the streaming api how does it work exactly? Right now I hit search, it calls the backend and returns an answer. In the streaming api however the code would *always* need to be running which would affect performance no? I want to search 24/7 for tweets of a certain keyword, for every user. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, calls come from their account - not the app's.  For more information, read [Twitter's Rate Limit documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1).
2. You need a long-lived HTTP request which consume incrementally.  That means you open a connection to the streaming API and, whenever there is new activity, it sends the data to you.  It will always need to be running in the back end which amy impact your resources and the design on your system.  See the [streaming documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/connecting).